# Callback when file is added to list

Tags: fine-uploader

When using the [FineUploader jQuery plugin](http://fineuploader.com)... I have autoUpload = false and I need to know when a file is added to the ul. The submit callback is called before the li is added. (I have some other elements as part of my "fileTemplate" that I need to update when a file is added.)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: please post a link the plugin you are using.

Comment: sorry, I've edited my post to note that I'm using the FineUploader plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely addressed in a case already implemented in the 3.4-IP branch.  3.4 is the next scheduled release.  Essentially, I have added an `onSubmitted` callback.  In your case, it is safe to assume that this callback will be invoked only after the list item has been added to the DOM.  Please let me know if this does not address your issue.